# Why is my MySQL Index not working on SQLFiddle?

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

Here is my table:

```
create table item (`Product ID` int not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Per/Unit` varchar(50) not null,
Product varchar(50) not null,
Details varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY (`Product ID`));

INSERT INTO item(Product,Details,`Per/Unit`)
VALUES
('Big Burger Deluxe','Single Patty with Cheese','$1.99'),
('Double Big','2 Patties on a Bun','$2.99'),
('Happy Size Fries','10oz Fries w/ Seasoning','$0.99'),
('Chocolate Shake','Thick Chocolate Shake','$1.49'),
('Strawberry Shake','Thick Strawberry Shake','$1.49'),
('Cherry Pie','Deep-fried cherry Pie with Cream Cheese Icing.','$1.29');create View item_view as select Product from item;

create index i1 on item(Product);
```

and here is my SELECT statement:

```
select * from item USE INDEX(i1);
```

What I get as an outcome:
[What I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axGYw.png)

What I want the outcome to be:
[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhVIL.png)

I'm following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html as a guideline but to no avail....

**UPDATE** THESE ARE MY INSTRUCTIONS

Develop SQL code to create an “Index” for the product name field
using the table that contains the product information fields by
doing the following:

1)Provide the SQL code you wrote to create the “Index” for the
product information.

---

I figured it out. Working index:[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VawYi.png)
Updated code:

```
create table item (`Product ID` int not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`Per/Unit` varchar(50) not null,
Product varchar(50) not null, Details varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (`Product ID`)); INSERT INTO item(Product,Details,`Per/Unit`) 
VALUES
('Big Burger Deluxe','Single Patty with Cheese','$1.99'),
('Double Big','2 Patties on a Bun','$2.99'),
('Happy Size Fries','10oz Fries w/ Seasoning','$0.99'),
('Chocolate Shake','Thick Chocolate Shake','$1.49'),
 ('Strawberry Shake','Thick Strawberry Shake','$1.49'),
('Cherry Pie','Deep-fried cherry Pie with Cream Cheese Icing.','$1.29');
create View item_view as select Product from item;
 create index `i1` on `item` (`Product` ASC);
```

---

Comment: selecting  all rows without a where condition don't use index  ..(you not asking to the db engine rows that can be reached  using index .. ) +

Comment: If you want only the product names you need to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT Product`.

Comment: See update as I must use an index for completion of this project.

Comment: I figured it out...

create index `i1` on `item` (`Product` ASC); 

then query 'select Product from item'